# WP8 storyboard color animation throwing invalid operation exception

Tags: windows-phone-8, storyboard, coloranimation

I'm trying to animate stackpanel background color on tap event to highlight it. Stackpanel is inside longlistselector. when i tap on particular element i want to highlight it
code is as below

**xaml code**

```
**<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToForegroundConverter x:Key="BooleanToForegroundConverter"/>
<Style x:Key="MyLongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle" 
       TargetType="toolkit:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
                            <StackPanel 
                        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},  
                                             Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToForegroundConverter}}">
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>**
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                                                  SelectionChanged="lstSongs_SelectionChanged"
                                                   GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource BuddiesGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                                                   Background="Transparent"
                                                   JumpListStyle="{StaticResource AddrBookJumpListStyle}"
                                                   HideEmptyGroups="True"

                                                   x:Name="lstSongs"
                                                   toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"        
                                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Songs}"
                               **ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyLongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle}"**                     
                                                   IsSelectionEnabledChanged="lstSongs_IsSelectionEnabledChanged" 
                                                     >
                                <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel   
                                    Margin="-40,0,0,17" 
                                    Width="432" 
                                    Height="78"
                                    Tap="OnTap"
                                   >
                                    <TextBlock 
                                        Text="{Binding Name}"  
                                        Margin="0,-15,0,0"
                                        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                                        Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock  
                                        Text="{Binding Artist.Name}"   
                                        Margin="12,-6,12,0"

                                        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

**And Converter implementation**

```
namespace musicplayer
{
    class BooleanToForegroundConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush:new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

**C# code ontap event**

    private void OnTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
            {
                //BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as AudioTrack;
                //BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
                Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
                ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();

                animation.To = (System.Windows.Media.Color)App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
                animation.AutoReverse = true;
                animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                StackPanel sp = sender as StackPanel;
                Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, sp);
                PropertyPath colorTargetPath = new PropertyPath("(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, colorTargetPath);
                storyBoard.Children.Add(animation);
               storyBoard.Begin();
        }
```

But I'm getting Invalid operation exception on  storyBoard.Begin(); line. 
What am I missing?? I'm just started learning windows phone 8 so any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't do this in code-behind. Override the LongListMultiSelectorItem Style and use a converter for the desired element. Something like the following

```
<Style x:Key="MyLongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle" 
       TargetType="toolkit:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
    <Style.Setters>                
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
                    <StackPanel 
                        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},  
                                             Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToForegroundConverter}}">                                
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

I'm not posting the converter implementation, it's fairly simple. Return the desired brush based on the boolean value.

Comment: I'm new to windows phone development. Can you please explain me whats going on in this code-> Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},  
                                             Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToForegroundConverter}}" and i want that animation to happen onTap of stackpanel

Comment: The LongListMultiSelectorItem has a boolean IsSelected dependency property which is getting updated whenever you select/unselect an item.  Essentially tapping on an item in your LongListMultiSelector tweeks that property. This line of XAML binds the background of your stackpanel to that property and uses a converter to return a desired brush.

Comment: I'm trying to use what you have suggested. But now i'm getting exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Cannot create instance of type 'musicplayer.BooleanToForegroundConverter'. I editted Code which i modified

Comment: There was some problem. Converter class wasnt public. Now i made it proper. But now LongListMultiSelector items are not getting displayed. I'm just getting group headers. Can you please figure out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Delete the inline ItemTemplate you have inside the LongListMultiSelector and place it on the Style, if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I got the list back. But highlighting is not happening. Is that the problem with converter?

Comment: What does the output window say? There should be a message for binding exceptions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57824/discussion-between-pantelis-and-user2354187).

Comment: There is no binding exceptions but still panel is not getting highlighted when I tap. And i was programmatically enabling EnforceIsSelectionEnabled property of LongListMultiSelector. But after adding Item style its not enabling that property. I couldnt able to select the items

Comment: If you just copied and pasted the Style I posted, it won't work. The default style comes with a bunch of Visual States you have to set. If you use VS 2013, select the control in the visual designer, right-click it and select edit a Template -> Edit a copy. Then on the style's template replace the ContentPresenter Control named Presenter with your StackPanel and the elements inside it. Use the same name for the StackPanel cause it is used in the Visual States. If you're using an older version of VS open your project in Blend and follow the same procedure.